# Autoplay muted video doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html5-video, autoplay

Just found out that a background video on the slider of the header doesn't autoplay in Chrome, but works well in Safari.

Here's a website: http://graddev.diamond-discovery.com/ems/

What could cause the issue? It plays for 1 second and then just freezes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Slick Slider, this code helped:

```
$('.hero-slider').on('init', function(slick){
    $('.hero-slider video').each(function () {
        this.play();
    });
});
```